# How could I use Select2 with TailwindCSS?

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I'm using TailwindCSS for a project and I must use Select2 (with laravel).

The problem is, the css formatting (nor the dropdown js mechanics) won't apply to the Select2 multiple checkbox.

I have the needed

```
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

links in my header as the [installation guide](https://select2.org/getting-started/installation) says (I'm using CDN)

Not even the first example (next page) shows up for me correctly...

What should I do?

If you need more information, ask and I'll update the description.

Comment: Hi there, is there any update on this ? Please do share your findings.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately nothing. I tried several things for weeks, but at the end I just gave it up.